# java code reading excel cell value which is (91.58666666666% rounded off and mentioned as 91.58) as zero, using PoI

Tags: selenium, automation, apache-poi

Below code is for reading as per data type and adding in collection which is row.

This code is returning Zero Value of Excel cell which contains Value "91.58666666666%"

```
case (Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING):
                                //System.out.println("***********Inside String ******"+"i-->"+i+"j-->"+j);
                                row.add(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case (Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC):
                                //System.out.println("***********Inside Integer ******");
                                int t = (int) sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
                               // System.out.println("***********TVALUE ******"+Integer.toString(t));
                                row.add(Integer.toString(t));
                                break;      
                            case (Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK):
                                //System.out.println("***********Inside String ******"+"i-->"+i+"j-->"+j);
                                //System.out.println("***********Blank ******"+sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                                row.add(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case (Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA):
                                //System.out.println("***********Inside String ******"+"i-->"+i+"j-->"+j);
                                //System.out.println("***********Blank ******"+sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                                DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
                                String valueAsSeenInExcel = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
                                row.add(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            default:
                                //DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
                                // Once per cell
                                //String valueAsSeenInExcel = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
                                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                row.add(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                                break;
```

Comment: Show the output in the question. You should log the exact results you get from your methods so you understand what you are trying to turn into a String later. (Also, please fixup your formatting, and maybe show more code so it is closer to a [mcve].

Comment: Just guessing, but if 91.6% gets turned into zero, it's probably because at some point it's being converted to an integer.  That would yield 0, not 91.

Comment: Please always add a tag for the language you're using.  I'm guessing this is Java.

Answer (score 1):

These lines are probably the culprit:

```
int t = (int) sh1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
row.add(Integer.toString(t));
```

Since the value is less than 1, it'll get truncated to zero.  Percentages are stored as floating point values, where 100% = 1.0 .

Use floating point!